# Make Divider match width of shrink-wrapped container?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to build a widget containing two `Text` widgets and one `Divider` widget, stacked vertically. The `Divider` should have the same width as the wider of the two `Text` widgets. The whole combined widget should consume no more layout space than its visible elements; that is, it should be shrink-wrapped.

I would like it to look like the following image:

[image]

(I added the light gray background here only to make my desired bounding box more apparent.)

It is unclear to me how to simultaneously force the widget hierarchy to assume the natural maximum width of the text while causing the `Divider` to stretch to a width only as great as the width of the text. If possible, I would like to do this without writing any custom layout widgets and without directly assigning a width to the `Divider` using measurements of widgets following the first layout or rendering pass.

Here is some code I tried in DartPad (https://dartpad.dev/flutter), but, naturally, it does not have the desired effect:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
      child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
        Text("Lorem ipsum"),
        Text("dolor"),
        Divider(thickness: 1.0, color: Colors.red),
      ]),
    )));
  }
}
```

My end goal is to have code that works in Android Studio 3.5.3, Windows 10 64-bit.
How can I fix (or replace) my code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use IntrinsicWidth see https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e for detailed options

https://dartpad.dev/79edda902aa584124dafd56c35d612fd

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: 
     Center(child: IntrinsicWidth(
        child:Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min , children: <Widget>[
        Text("Lorem ipsum"),
        Text("dolor"),
        Divider(thickness: 1.0, color: Colors.red),
      ]))),
    ));
  }
}
```